How can i connect my springboot micro service to an MSK with IAM authentiaction?
Im trying to connect my project with this configuration

    @Bean
    public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin() {
        
        Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
        configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        configs.put(AdminClientConfig.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SASL_SSL");
        configs.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, "AWS_MSK_IAM");
        configs.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, "software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required awsProfileName=\"ATKAFKA\" awsStsRegion=\"us-east-1\";");
        configs.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_CLIENT_CALLBACK_HANDLER_CLASS, "software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler");
        
        configs.put(AdminClientConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 30000); // 30 segundos
        configs.put(AdminClientConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 5);
        configs.put("sasl.aws.accessKeyId", accessKey);
        configs.put("sasl.aws.secretAccessKey", secretKey);
        return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
    }

But im getting this error:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SaslAuthenticationException: An error: (java.security.PrivilegedActionException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Failed to find AWS IAM Credentials [Caused by software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from any of the providers in the chain AwsCredentialsProviderChain(credentialsProviders=[ProfileCredentialsProvider(profileName=ATKAFKA, profileFile=ProfileFile(sections=[])), AwsCredentialsProviderChain(credentialsProviders=[EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider(), SystemPropertyCredentialsProvider(), WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider(), ProfileCredentialsProvider(profileName=default, profileFile=ProfileFile(sections=[])), ContainerCredentialsProvider(), InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider()])]) : [ProfileCredentialsProvider(profileName=ATKAFKA, profileFile=ProfileFile(sections=[])): Profile file contained no credentials for profile 'ATKAFKA': ProfileFile(sections=[]), AwsCredentialsProviderChain(credentialsProviders=[EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider(), SystemPropertyCredentialsProvider(), WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider(), ProfileCredentialsProvider(profileName=default, profileFile=ProfileFile(sections=[])), ContainerCredentialsProvider(), InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider()]): Unable to load credentials from any of the providers in the chain AwsCredentialsProviderChain(credentialsProviders=[EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider(), SystemPropertyCredentialsProvider(), WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider(), ProfileCredentialsProvider(profileName=default, profileFile=ProfileFile(sections=[])), ContainerCredentialsProvider(), InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider()]) : [EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider(): Unable to load credentials from system settings. Access key must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) or system property (aws.accessKeyId)., SystemPropertyCredentialsProvider(): Unable to load credentials from system settings. Access key must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) or system property (aws.accessKeyId)., WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider(): Either the environment variable AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE or the javaproperty aws.webIdentityTokenFile must be set., ProfileCredentialsProvider(profileName=default, profileFile=ProfileFile(sections=[])): Profile file contained no credentials for profile 'default': ProfileFile(sections=[]), ContainerCredentialsProvider(): Cannot fetch credentials from container - neither AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_FULL_URI or AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI environment variables are set., InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(): Failed to load credentials from IMDS.]]]) occurred when evaluating SASL token received from the Kafka Broker. Kafka Client will go to AUTHENTICATION_FAILED state

I need to connect my project to the MSK

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The exception you are getting indicates that your app cannot find AWS credentials (Profile file contained no credentials for profile 'ATKAFKA').
Most probably it's because you don't have your file.
Make sure you have a credentials file under ~/.aws/, and this file should have section ATKAFKA with access key, secutity key, session token, etc.
If this file contains only default, remove profile definition from the properties:
        configs.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, "software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required ;");


Do you have an example of how to do the credential file or a project that use that?

you should be able to set up the credentials using CLI. Please refer to the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/v1/userguide/cli-configure-files.html
